# Cal-Heatmap legend colors for qualitative categories

Tags: css, d3.js, heatmap

I'm trying to create a [cal-heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#home) with a qualitative color legend for 9 categories (labeled 1-9). I'm using the following CSS to set the colors:

```
<style type="text/css">
.q8{fill:rgb(141, 211, 199);}
.q7{fill:rgb(255, 255, 179);}
.q6{fill:rgb(190, 186, 218);}
.q5{fill:rgb(251, 128, 114);}
.q4{fill:rgb(128, 177, 211);}
.q3{fill:rgb(253, 180, 98);}
.q2{fill:rgb(179, 222, 105);}
.q1{fill:rgb(252, 205, 229);}
.q0{fill:rgb(217, 217, 217);}
```

With this:

```
var cal_cluster = new CalHeatMap();
cal_cluster.init({
  itemSelector: "#chart2",
  itemName: ["Cluster", "Cluster"],
  domain: "month",
  subDomain: "day",
  domainLabelFormat: "%b-%Y",
  data: "data.json",
  start: new Date(2012, 02),
  maxDate: new Date(2013, 04),
  cellSize: 16,
  range: 5, animationDuration: 1000,
  subDomainTextFormat: "%d",
  nextSelector: "#domainDynamicDimension-next",
  previousSelector: "#domainDynamicDimension-previous",
  legend: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  legendCellSize: 15,
});
```

However the last two categories are not rendering properly:

[image: cal-heatmap legend problem]

However, using the `legendColors` option works properly (although I don't want a sequential scale):

```
  legendColors: {
    empty: "#ededed",
    min: "#40ffd8",
    max: "#f20013"
  }
```

[image: cal-heatmap proper rendering]

Also, are there better ways of creating categorical color scales for cal-heatmap?

Comment: Have you seen [the color scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A legend array of N values will generate a legend of N + 1 colors. Each colors correspond to a CSS class, formatted like .q{n}.

So you need a `.q9` and a `.q10` class.

Remember that `.q0` is not counted, as it's a special class used for dates with a value equal to 0.